# Computer won't start when plugging in sata power cable to power supply

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, sata, power

I just bought a hard drive for my PC and connected it to the motherboard and psu. Once I started the computer it refuses to start, I removed the sata power cable and the sata cable, and the pc started to work again, when plugging back in the sata cable to the motherboard the pc worked aswell, but when plugging in the sata power cable to the psu it refuses to work.

I replaced the sata power cable with another one that came in the box with the psu and it only gave me the same problem. I also gave my friend the hard drive just to see if it worked and it worked with no problem.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What help do you need? The hard drive was broken already when you got it, so return it? Unless it works on another computer.

Comment: Your PSU might have insufficient power for adding one more disk. If that's the case, you need a better PSU.

Comment: I just want the computer to work, with the hard drive connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before by others, either your PSU is malfunctioning or it doesn't have enough power to supply energy to the system with one more disk.
You can try, if you have another disc or a DVD drive, to disconnect one and connect only your new disk. If the system boots, your PSU is not potent enough, if it doesn't boot, it's faulty.
Either way, I'm afraid that your only solution is to replace the PSU.

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced the PSU, and it worked fine. so it must have been a problem with the PSU

Answer (score 0):

When the drive worked fine when connected to the PSU of your friend, your PSU is most likely broken and needs to be replaced.

In case it's a shucked HDD and it's just the HDD that refuses to spin up (and not the whole PC), it's caused by the common 3.3V pin issue with these drives.